# MongoDB nodejs: How to modify the value of a field within an object searched by another field

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

How can i modify the value of a field searching the object by another field?

the object looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "607b8b1fdd12a63f0499c207"
    },
    "username": "paul",
    "password": "123456",
    "question": "q2",
    "answer": "cucu"
}
```

and i wanna modify the password, searching the object by the username,
i tried this but does not work:

```
var dbc = db.db("chat");
dbc.collection("accounts").update({username: { $eq: user}},{$set: { password : newpass}});
```

Comment: provide the error you get, or the whole code you've written to be able to get the big picture, if you you think the problem is query, which seems not, test you're query in mongodb compass or mongo shell first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me ({$eq: "paul"} is the same of "paul" in this case)

```
db.getCollection('accounts').update({username:"paul"},{$set: { password : "newpass"}})
```